# How do I retrieve a call path with xref

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to retrieve the path between two function from the call graph of a set of modules using xref.

Consider the following functions calling each other:

```
x:a/1 -> y:b/1 -> y:c/1
x:d/1 -> y:e/1
```

using the query: `closure E | a:Mod || b:Mod` will give me tuples of the start- and end-points of the paths of any direct or indirect call from module a to module b. Thus for the above example:

```
[{{x,a,1}, {y,b,1}},
 {{x,a,1}, {y,c,1}},
 {{x,d,1}, {y,e,1}}]
```

This is the set of paths through the call graph that I am looking for, but I need the inner verticies as well. For the above example this would be:

```
[[{x,a,1}, {y,b,1}],
 [{x,a,1}, {y,b,1}, {y,c,1}],
 [{x,d,1}, {y,e,1}]]
```

I have tried various variations of the examples given in the XRef documentation. I do understand that the query language operates on sets of verticies and edges, but fail to grasp a number of selection mechanism.

I am using the xref command of rebar3 to work with the queries, all the relevant code is in the project that I call rebar from. I am actually trying to show how the tests are calling the functions in the module.

Side question: Is there any more gentle introduction to the xref query language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully you can use this code snippet as a starting point:

```
q(X) ->
    {ok, L} = xref:q(X, "closure E | x:Mod || y:Mod"),
    l(X, L).

l(_, []) -> [];
l(X, [{F,T}|L]) ->
    Q = io_lib:format("{~p, ~p} of E", [F, T]),
    {ok, Path} = xref:q(X, lists:flatten(Q)),
    [Path | l(X, L)].
```

Comment: I had hoped for a solution directly in xref (with rebar help)